# How to use Laravel WebSockets with IIS8?

Tags: iis, iis-8, laravel-websockets

I am using Laravel Websockets (by BeyondCode) - https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction. May I know how can I install it on IIS8? I have no problem configured it on localhost.

Comment: I am not an expert in laravel websocket, but according to the description in the documentation, this seems to be configured in php. IIS supports the use of FastCGI to run php applications.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configure-a-php-website-on-iis